# How to concatenate two strings and save in third variable in C?

Tags: c

I have defined a `char` array with a predefined HTTP post string like this:

```
char header[] = "POST /api/add HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: xxxxxxx:3000\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Length: 500\r\nName: ";

strcat(header, strDevicename); \\
strcat(header, "\r\n\r\n");
```

where the `strDevicename` is a `char` variable name changed every request.
The problem is when I run it for the first time, it is working but after that getting overwritten `Name` with `a96ed5ÿÿa96ed58e8355`.

What is the best way to add two string with one real-time change variable using C languages in HTTP post header?

Comment: You need to create a buffer big enough to hold the two strings plus the NULL-terminator

Comment: ...and you should read the chapter dealing with strings in your C text book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are [str]concatenating to an array (`header`) which doesn't extra space (C arrays can't be changed in size).

[`snprintf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) could be a better fit here.

If you know the maximum possible length of `strDevicename`, you could use a fixed size buffer:

```
const char header[] = "POST /api/add HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: xxxxxxx:3000\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Length: 500\r\nName: ";
const char tail[] = "\r\n\r\n";
char buf[(sizeof header - 1) + MAX_DEV_LENGTH + (sizeof tail - 1) + 1];
/* sizeof would count the null byte in header & tail arrays. */
snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%s%s%s", header, strDevicename, tail);
```

If `strDevicename` is of unknown length, you could use [`asprintf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html)(GNU function):

```
char *buf = NULL;
if (asprintf(&buf, "%s%s%s", header, strDevicename, tail) == -1) {
   /* handle memory allocation failure */
}

...

free(buf);
```

If you `asprintf` isn't available, then you could allocate sufficient memory (just as above) yourself using [`malloc`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realloc.3.html) and then use `snprintf`.

Comment: Don't you think that `sprintf` function is an overkill for the sting concatenation ?

Comment: Possibly. Arguable if it's worse than N(=2 here) `strcat` calls (`strcat` is also vulnerable to buffer overflows. So in the "fixed size buffer" approach, a call to `strlen` becomes necessary to ensure the length of `strDevicename`). But if I am worried about performance, I'd measure first.

Comment: `printf` is a very heavy function. Needs to parse the format string first. And not everyone writes programs for the computers with (almost) infinitive resources. Imagine small uC with 4k Flash and printf will take 3.5k..

Comment: And how much memory you'd need for a HTTP request & response on such systems? ( that's likely what OP does).

Comment: Overkill or not -- I don't think the OP is at the performance optimization step yet.

Comment: Great..!!! But i am used following way:
sprintf((char*)headerbuf,"POST /api/add HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: xxxxxxx:3000\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Length: 500\r\nName: %s\r\n\r\n", strDevicename);

Comment: @vishalB That's almost certainly undefined behaviour because `header` array does not have space to append to. `snprintf` is the better version of `sprintf` (sprintf is vulnerable to buffer overflow).

Answer (score 4):

In your code, the size of the array `header` is decided by the size of the supplied initializer string, and it does not have any additional space to store (or *append*) any further characters.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.9

> If an array of unknown size is initialized, its size is determined by the largest indexed
>   element with an explicit initializer. The array type is completed at the end of its
>   initializer list.

Next, for `strcat()`, from chapter §7.24.3.1

> The `strcat` function appends a copy of the string pointed to by `s2` (including the
>   terminating null character) to the end of the string pointed to by `s1`. [...]

which indicates, the target `s1` (here, `header`) should have sufficient storage to hold the concatenated string.

Thus, the attempt to `strcat()` with `header` as source, invokes undefined behaviour here, as you run past allocated memory.

You need to make `header` have enough space left after you fill it with the initializer string. Use a fixed size for the array, which has much excess after filling it with the initialize string, something like

```
#define STRSIZ 512

char header[STRSIZ] = "POST /api/add HTT.........
```

Answer (score 2):

From `man 3 strcat`:

> The strings may not overlap, and the dest string must have enough space for the result. If dest is not large enough, program behavior is unpredictable; *buffer overruns are a favorite avenue for attacking secure programs*.

You need to ensure your `header` array is allocated large enough to ensure that you can write `strlen(strDeviceName) + 5` bytes into it in addition to the initial size; otherwise you have a (probably remotely exploitable) buffer overrun vulnerability.

Presumably `header` is allocated locally to the function? In that case you should consider using `alloca` or `malloc` to get a properly-sized block of memory rather than relying on a static size. You'll also need to handle errors from those functions.

Additionally, you should always prefer the safe alternative `strncat` over plain `strcat`, as `strncat` takes an additional argument for the number of bytes to append, and ensures that the buffer is always null-terminated even if an overflow would otherwise have happened.

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate sufficient space for the entire string. 
Man page:

```
char * strcat(char *restrict s1, const char *restrict s2);
The string s1 must have sufficient space to hold the result.
```

You could do it the "right" way and allocate exactly what you need:

```
char *buf;
char header[] = "POST /api/add HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: xxxxxxx:3000\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Length: 500\r\nName: "

buf = malloc(strlen(header)+strlen(strDeviceName)+strlen("\r\n\r\n")+1);
if(buf==NULL) abort();
strcpy(buf, header);
strcat(buf, strDevicename); \\
strcat(buf, "\r\n\r\n");
```

Or do it the lazy way and overallocate:

```
char header[1024] = "POST /api/add HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: xxxxxxx:3000\r\nContent-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8\r\nContent-Length: 500\r\nName: "

strcat(header, strDevicename); \\
strcat(header, "\r\n\r\n");
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Any advice on correcting this answer?

Answer (score 0):

As you need to have enough space you can duplicate both in the new one:

```
char *mystrcat(const char *src1, const *char src2)
{
    char *dest
    size_t src1Len = strlen(src1);
    dest = malloc(src1Len + strlen(src2) + 1);
    if(dest)
    {
        memcpy(dest, src1, src1Len);
        strcpy(dest + src1Len, src2);
    }
    return dest;
}
```